# Converting varchar to int (a strange case?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have scoured through all "Varchar to Int" posts but can't seem to find anyone with this issue (although, I am fairly new to SQL so I may be doing something fundamentally wrong):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE CONVERT(INT,
        CASE
        WHEN NOT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dept_code) LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 8900 
        END) < 9000;
```

It's a fairly simple query, where the goal is to filter out all the values in field "dept_code" so that only **fully numeric** values less than 9000 are kept; varchars and non-numeric values are fine to stay. When running the above **I still get the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'E103' to data type int."**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Neuro_Prog, do you know what version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1):

You can simply this query by avoiding `CASE` and `Regex` `like` expression. You can use [IsNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to filter numeric rows and then apply the condition by converting dept_code of filtered rows to int,  like below -

```
select * from tablex 
where ISNUMERIC(dept_code) = 0 --alphanumeric code
OR(ISNUMERIC(dept_code) = 1 and Convert(int, dept_code) < 9000) -- numeric less than 9000
```

[Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3fa83/8)

Comment: This works in the link you provided, but when I run it on my tables it gets stuck on "NONE". I even added "NONE" to the example you provided and it still works...

Comment: Yes, it's stating that there is no department code. Department codes can also be a mixture of letters and numbers such as "Z280".

Comment: Also, wouldn't ISNUMERIC be a poor choice since it will equal 1 even for strings like "5d8"?

Comment: ISNUMERIC will return 1 or 0, just like bolean. For "5d8", it will return 0. try my new query in the answer .

Comment: The query is executing longer that normal because it seems to not recognize that I also have: AND ledger_year_month = 201805 (meaning ledger date should only equal 05/2018). The query is running for random ledger_year_month as well

Comment: you can add that as a AND condition. Make sure to put OR condition dept_code in a brackaet. (Dep_code filter) AND (ledger_date filter)

Comment: Vinit, I think Neuro_Prog has a point. If the string has a numeric prefix ISNUMERIC considers it numeric even if not totally numbers. I get 1 for ISNUMERIC('5D8') http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1ea68/3

Comment: Sorry, same error as before (picking random dates) even with the brackets; any chance you could add the ledger_date filter to your example with the brackets as I may be doing something different?

Comment: @asantaballa Yep, that's why I had switched over to regex

Answer (score 1):

Use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM [TABLE] t
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, dept_code) < 9000
```

If you want to speed this query, you can materialize a computed column and add an index:

```
alter table [table] add dept_code_int as (try_convert(int, dept_code)) persisted;

create index idx_table_dept_code_int on [table](dept_code_int);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think is exactly what I need. However, when I go to run my implementation, it is so slow that the query times out... I am thinking about using non-clustered indexes to speed things but am not sure if this is the right approach. I can't post code here but this is approximately what the query looks like (sorry if messy): SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE ledger_year_month = 201805 AND TRY_CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, dept_code) IS NOT NULL THEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, dept_code) ELSE 0 END) <= 9000;

Comment: @Neuro_Prog . . . You must have a very large table.  Indexes will not help this query.

Comment: Any tips on how to move forward given the size of the table (millions of lines)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an else in your case statement ... Secondly do your numeric dept_codes get to be really big ... this thing will choke on that.

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE CONVERT(INT,
    CASE
    WHEN NOT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dept_code) LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 8900   ELSE dept_code 
    END) < 9000;
```

Comment: The department codes don't go above 4 digits but I am working with millions of lines so would that make it choke? When I add the ELSE statement it is now getting stuck on converting "NONE" to int which wasn't an issue previously. Thanks

Comment: what should it do for "NONE"?

Comment: It should keep the NONE, I am only trying to get rid of fully numeric values above 9000

Comment: I actually think this requires a custom function, a scalar function. I will look around later tonight. I may have one.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb6b7/17

```
;WITH TABLE_ENHANCED AS
(
  SELECT 
    t.*
  , dept_code_numeric =
      CASE
      WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dept_code) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
      THEN CONVERT(INT, dept_code)
      ELSE 0 
      END
  FROM [TABLE] t
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM TABLE_ENHANCED
WHERE dept_code_numeric < 9000
```

Comment: Hm, it's taking a very long time to run, will try tomorrow and check back in, thanks

Comment: Sorry! Calculated the numeric "value" but left or the selection for < 9000 so you may be selecting everything. Have edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Script

```
SELECT *
    FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE isnumeric(dept_code)=1 
and dept_code<9000;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The conversion to int is implicit.

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(dept_code)=1 and dept_code<9000)
or (ISNUMERIC(dept_code) = 0)
```